# Identify outliers for annotation in text data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, annotation, active-learning

I read the book "Human-in-the-Loop Machine Learning" by Robert (Munro) Monarch about Active Learning. I don't understand the following approach to get a diverse set of items for humans to label:

> 1. Take each item in the unlabeled data and count the average number of word matches it has with items already in the training data
> 2. Rank the items by their average match
> 3. Sample the item with the lowest average number of matches
> 4. Add that item to the ‘labeled’ data and repeat 1-3 until we have sampled enough for one iteration of human review

It's not clear how to calculate the average number of word matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find the documents which are not well represented in the current labeled data. The first point is indeed a bit vague and can probably be interpreted in different ways. My interpretation would be something like this:

- For every document $d_u$ in the unlabeled data, count the number of words in common with every document $d_l$ in the labeled data. This value is the "match score" between $d_u$ and $d_l$.

  - Note: I think that this value should be normalized, for example using the [overlap coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap_coefficient). Note that other similarity measures could be used as well, for instance cosine-TFIDF.
- As output from the above step, for a single document $d_u$ one obtains a "match score" for every labeled document. The average across the labeled documents gives the "average match" for $d_u$.

Comment: I checked the source code. For each word in a document, you need to count all matches in training (labeled) data, sum them up, and divide by the number of words in the document. This should be a simple approach as the author says.

Comment: @MykolaZotko ok, probably for this purpose just counting the matches is sufficient. But in general this approach would favor long documents over short ones, that's why I think normalizing is better (and it's not really more complex).